# Is my FPS limited by CPU or graphics card? Rotating 3D surfaces in Matlab

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, graphics, matlab, hardware-acceleration

I have a modern laptop. When I use Matlab to visualize a 3D surface with a large number of vertices, I can only get a frame rate around 5 FPS when rotating it. With transparent surfaces, only 1 FPS.

What is likely to be the limiting factor here? CPU or graphics card, or something else? Is there any way to find out for sure?

Some hardware info: Intel i7, 8 GB RAM, "Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller"

Comment: Considering your CPU is very powerful it is likely to be the GPU (which is integrated in your CPU) which is limitating.

Comment: Not to mention Intel GPUs are horribly slow, @Kwaio

Comment: They're not meant to be used for highly-requiring 3D tasks, but only basic 2D acceleration. You want 3D performance, you get up-to-scale hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely to be your graphics card.

Otherwise, you'd see other issues (like out of memory exceptions etc).

Of course, it's relative, a 'large number of verticies' is meaningless as it's undefined and it could be your CPU as well as the GPU.

You asked `is there any way to find out for sure`. The answer is, buy or even borrow a suitable external graphics card and try it. There could be other factors at play which we don't know about (such as your environment etc, what other tasks are going on in the background etc).

Also, making sure the best drivers are installed may help.

Comment: Thanks. About buying/borrowing a graphics card, since I'm using a laptop (and don't want to open it), I suppose that menas buying/borrowing an entire computer?

Comment: @Anna - as per my post, there are external graphics cards for laptops...